# react d3 line chart how to add up analytics data for each day/month

Tags: javascript, d3.js, react-d3

I am trying to add up data that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "jK7o8qnWzgpZzzB3s", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T03:31:02.619Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "NgwntGwSYq6RqiXXq", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T03:31:04.488Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "MSTJGeFvgtkHr6rs8", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T03:31:05.793Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "h76hpE9ATuTSqvMpp", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T03:31:06.668Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "hXNt6SNGDn3zKHMhH", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:51.688Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "k4WMxQDSPhiAhY2eK", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:52.737Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "2NBziCevCxC739Wte", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:53.048Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "b8ZTYmvowtNWEGQaE", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:53.257Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "Z7RsZzvrkntmRnGrG", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:53.472Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "aWwoypfDscqfXxWtY", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:53.676Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
{ "_id" : "9pC9zmqJRL6Qybfor", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-23T05:11:54.031Z"), "productId" : "rgKEMvDD9BnJCzPHJ", "productOwnerId" : "mEWFCknMFydfxowhf" }
```

I need to use the createdAt field as the x axis (for each day added up) and the sum of all those as the y axis.

Is there a way to do this with react d3 or do I need to add up each day myself?

Right now I am adding it up myself by no data on the graph is being shown.

this is the chart series and x function I am using:

```
var chartSeries = [
      {
        field: 'y',
        name: 'Number of Downloads For Day',
        color: '#ff7f0e'
      }
    ]
    tickFormatter = function(d) {
      console.log("what is d");
      console.log(d);
     return new Date(d.x);
   }
```

and this is how I am displaying the graph:

```
<LineChart data={downloadChartDataPoints} chartSeries={chartSeries} x={tickFormatter} />
```

Comment: I'm thinking that you'll have to do your own aggregations...

Comment: That's what I thought can't seem to get it working though.